# SetScrollPos is blocking

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

In my multithreaded mfc app, m_view->SetScrollPos is blocking and all the app is freezed. The View is created in another thread, is this the reason for such behavior?

```
//SetScrollPos(SB_HORZ,pos);
::SetScrollPos(GetSafeHwnd(), SB_HORZ, pos, true);
```

The same happens with `SetScrollInfo()`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple:

CHanging the scroll positions cause some window messages to be created. If you are in another thread and the thread hosting the window is not ready to process messages via the GetMessaage/PostMessage, the thread using SendMessage is blocked until the message can be delivered.

This is a normal and well documented behavior.

My advice: Never perform UI action from another thread. Choose a neutral communication method to inform the other thread about changes (PostMessage, Timer and data field, aso.)...

Comment: I tried to use `PostThreadMessage()` to do the setscrollpos in the ui thread, but the handler is not invoked. I checked that the ui thread is pumping other messages properly (it is not blocked).

Comment: Also could you answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967792/command-and-update-command-ui-handlers-not-called-in-mfc-dll